# How does the browser know I'm targeting ES6?

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm using Typescript and I recently changed the transpilation options to target ES6 instead of ES5.

I was using a certain syntax that had always worked fine under ES5, but after the target change, I started getting this error in the (Firefox) browser console:

```
Javascript ES6 TypeError: Class constructor Client cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I changed the code to a suitable syntax for ES6, and this fixed the issue, but I don't understand how the browser would know to throw this error in the first place, because the exact same code worked before.

Does the javascript parser in browser scan *other* parts of the code base and see they *they're* using ES6, and then reject this line because it doesn't match the ES6 code *elsewhere*?

Comment: Cause you weren't using a suitable syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't enter any particular "mode".

Likely what really happened is that you were declaring a `class Client`. That is ES6 syntax, and it comes with the special caveat that you must use `new Client` to instantiate it. Now, your compiler compiled this into a backwards-compatible `function Client() ...`. Obviously, you can call a `function` without `new`. And that's what you were doing somewhere.

So, the compilation from `class` to `function` masked the error. But when leaving the `class` as `class` (because ES6 target mode does not need to dumb it down to a `function`), the browser was actually dealing with a `class` and raised that error.

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense, thanks! I forgot that the object I was creating was also different with the different target.